# Jquery - missing ; before statement error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a minor problem but i dont know how to fix it i made a script with different settings but i receive an error

```
$(function() {
    $(".basket").hide();
    $(".opened").click(function(){
      $(".basket").slideToggle();
      $(".opened").toggleClass('active');
    });


    $(".black-block .showed").click(function(e){
      $(".black-block").find(".caption").slideToggle();
      $(".showed a").toggleClass('active');
    });
    $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#c1r",
        btnPrev: "#c1l",
        easing: "easeOutQuad",
        visible: 5,

    });
    var currentSlide = 1;
    var currentPage = 0;
    $('#slideshow').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
                effect: 'slide',
                crossfade: true,
            play: 5000,
                slideSpeed: 350,
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                generateNextPrev: true,
                generatePagination: false,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('').animate({
                        bottom:-155
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };

                    var newPage = Math.floor(currentSlide / 6);

                    if (newPage > currentPage) { // Page must be greater
                        $('#c1r').trigger('click');
                    }
                     else (newPage < currentPage) { // Page must be less
                        $('#c1l').trigger('click');
                    }                    
                    currentPage = newPage;
                    currentSlide = current;
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
```

According to Firebug the error should be here:

```
else (newPage < currentPage) { // Page must be less
                    $('#c1l').trigger('click');
```

Since i am out of idea it would be awesome if maybe someone can give ma hint whats wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $('').animate({... ??? is that empty??

Comment: Should `currentSlide = current;` be `currentSlide = currentPage;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
else (newPage < currentPage) { // Page must be less
```

to

```
else if (newPage < currentPage) { // Page must be less
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `if` keyword after `else` and before that conditional statement `newPage < currentPage`

```
else if(newPage < currentPage) { 
  // Page must be less
     $('#c1l').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: @Starx i think i have more detail in my answer than rahul, I have also mentioned where that `if` is missing.

Comment: You didn't in your first post. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a extra trailing comma here:

```
$(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: "#c1r",
    btnPrev: "#c1l",
    easing: "easeOutQuad",
    visible: 5,

});
```

If you use a good ide (I suggest WebStorm), it'll catch these pesky errors for you.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an `if`:

```
else if(newPage < currentPage)
```

anyway passing your code on lint reveals multiple warnings you can check them here: 
http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Answer (score 0):

You've missed an `if` keyword after `else`:

it is actually `else if` instead of `if`

Try:

```
if (newPage > currentPage) { // Page must be greater
      $('#c1r').trigger('click');
 }
 else if (newPage < currentPage) { // Page must be less
      $('#c1l').trigger('click');
 }
```